# How to boost fields in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrnet, edismax, dismax

I already have the boost determined before hand. I have a field in the solr index called `boost1` . This boost field will have a value from 1 to 10 similar to google PR rank. This is the boost that should be applied to every query ran in solr. here are the fields in my index

- Id
- Title
- Text
- Boost1

The boost field should be apply to every query. I am trying to implement functionality similar to Google PR rank. Is there a way to do this using solr?

Comment: This is still (from 2012) informative and helpful: https://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can add the boost during query e.g.

```
q={!boost b=boost1}
```

[How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents)

However, this may need to be added explicitly by you.

If you are using `dismax` or `edismax` with the request handler,  The bf (Boost Functions) parameter could be used to boost the documents.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29

```
bf=boost1^0.5
```

This can be added to defaults with the request handler definition, so that they are applied to all the search queries.

you can use function queries to vary the amount of boost [FunctionQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery)

Comment: Hi, How to do a more complex function query to achieve a boost using multiplication.. pls check at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874983/use-function-query-for-boosting-score-in-solr

Comment: You might want to prefer the `boost` (multiplicative boost) to the `bf` (additive boost) parameter in `edismax` queries. An article that sheds some light on the all the different parameters: https://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/

Comment: Works for me, great! But I don't understand why. I don't find anything about `!boost b=...` in the Reference Guide of Solr 8.x or 9.x. Could you give some more explanation about what is going on exactly? The links you provided are not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [index time document boosts](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts).  See [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_on_.22doc.22) if you are indexing XML or [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Special_Commands) if using `DataImportHandler`.