# Magento Solr: Increase weight of title in schema.xml?

Tags: magento, solr

I have a Magento-installation with Solr search. This works fairly well although it doesnt give relevant hits on a few queries. It seems that the the "title" attribute is not weighed higher than other attributes such as "description".  Is there any way to define that title should have a higher weight in schema.xml?

Or any other ideas on how to manipulate the search results of a specific product? E.g. adding another attribute with some meta keywords?

I'm new to Solr so any feedback is appreciated!

My schema.xml is located [here](http://pastebin.com/VDA9iAKJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called 'boosting' .

You can do boosting at index-time (more performant at query time) and at query-time (more flexible)

More here: 
[How to boost fields in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701671/how-to-boost-fields-in-solr)