# Use function query for boosting score in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solrnet, solr4

I working on a Solr 4 for optimizing my solr results rank based on popularity rank stored in Index.

Now when someone searches, apart from relevancy rank, I want to influence relevancy rank using popularity rank. The simplest formula could be:

> new relavancy rank = score * popularityrank

I have been looking at Solr function query at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#product to achieve the same however, I'm not sure how to get it to work. I didn't get how to get score multiplied using product function. Trying to get it done, I always get error as field not defined.

Now I can use boost as defined here [How to boost fields in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701671/how-to-boost-fields-in-solr), but I have additional logic/requirement where I want to use functional query provided by Solr.

For example, I have tried with following simple query that seems to work

```
http://solr:8983/solr/select?q=hp%20laptop&defType=edismax&fl=Id,Name,score&bf=product%28$v1,$v2%29&v1=Id&v2=2
```

Now, for my actual requirement, I want to take score as $v2, however I am not able to find how to do this.

Any help is highly appreicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr Function Query : How to use "score" field for creating custom scoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838557/solr-function-query-how-to-use-score-field-for-creating-custom-scoring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `_val_` hook provided by Solr.

For instance, in order to sort by `score * popularityrank`, try using this

```
http://solr:8983/solr/select?q=hp%20laptop&_val_="product(score,popularityrank)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We will try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use query() function to get the value of 'score' instead.

So if you're trying for this: **new_score = score * popularity** , use the following format.

q=searchterm&**sort=product(query($q),popularity)** desc

query($q) - returns the TF-IDF score for the query. So this is the equivalent of using the 'score' field.